CSS Файл подключен, но свойства не работают (node.js)
Мой node.js code:
// --Config
const express = require('express')
const server = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(server)
const io = require("socket.io")(http)
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

http.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

// -- Styles
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))

// --Pages
server.get('/', function(request, respons){
    respons.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

// --Requests
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("test", function(){
    })
})

Мой html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" href="assets/main.css">
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <menu>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="navigation">Hello</div>
            <div class="login"></div>
        </nav>
    </menu>
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        let socket = io()
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Вот так у меня выглядит директория:

Никаких ошибок в консоли нету, файл подключен как я понял, но при этом никакие свойства не применяются

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Посмотрите наличие ошибок в консоли и на сервере. Так же попробуйте вставить путь до css в браузер и посмотреть результат

Если перейти по пути через сервер то выдает: Cannot GET /assets/main.css
Если по пути на компьютере то я получаю просто свойства из CSS файла
В консоли никаких ошибок нету

server.use(express.static(...)) применяют после основных маршрутов. Уберите его в самый низ. 1. get 2. static 3. listen ... и отключите на время сокеты. Дело сейчас не в них, а в первых трёх пунктах, но судя по вашему коду может быть что угодно.

Я убрал часть кода вниз которую вы сказали и получил в консоли это - GET
http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

Похоже, что вы некорректно задали статический каталог. вот примеры - Попробуйте так: server.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets')). Ну и в целом проверьте корректность пути до этого каталога(выведете в лог __dirname + /assets)

Это говорит о том, что у вас ещё где-то "собака порылась".  Собственно SwaD вам уже посоветовал. Вам бы следовало указвать пути при помощи path.join() Но можете и сами попробовать перед listen добавить в код ваш путь  console.log( __dirname + '/assets' )  и посмотреть в выводе консоли куда он ведёт.

В консоль выводит путь куда надо, я сейчас добавлю ответ со скринами

Проблема решена, добавил 'server.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))' в конец и вернул rel="stylesheet", спасибо
